# Core Graphics on Retina Display = wrong png size

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics

I have an iOS app that takes a photo using the camera, crops it square and then overlays a png on top. It works but the @2x retina image doesn't respect it's 640x640 original size and is displayed at 1280x1280 (the retina size)

This means the original photo and overlay aren't lined up.

Any help?

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
[imageView setImage:image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

UIImage *borderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Overlay4.png"]];

NSData *dataFromImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1);


CIImage *beginImage= [CIImage imageWithData:dataFromImage];

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *border =[CIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(borderImage)];

CIFilter *filter= [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];  
[filter setDefaults];
[filter setValue:border forKey:@"inputImage"];

[filter setValue:beginImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];

CIImage *outputImage = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

imageView.image = newImg;
```

}

Comment: Why are you converting border image back to png and then creating the CIImage from that (and thus losing the scale property)?  Why not just create the CIImage directly from the UIImage (`CIImage* border = borderImage.CIImage;`)?  That might solve the problem since the scale property might be maintained (doesn't look like it, but...)  In any case it would make the whole process faster.

Comment: Sorry @David but where would this code go?

Comment: You have two different sequences of UIImage... = something, data = UIImageXXXRepresentation, CIImage = [CIImage imageWithData:data].  Both can be replaced by using [uiImage CIImage]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in xcode 5+, try looking at the media.xcassets folder and seeing where "overlay4.png" is placed (in the 1x or 2x box).

It might be as simple as moving it over.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will actually solve your problem, but it replaces the questionable usages of UIImageXXXRepresentation and imageWithData:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    UIImage *borderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Overlay4.png"]];
    CIImage *border = [borderImage CIImage];

    CIImage *beginImage= [image CIImage];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CIFilter *filter= [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];
    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:border forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [filter setValue:beginImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];

    CIImage *outputImage = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:outputImage];

    imageView.image = newImg;
}
```

Which may allow scale parameters to be maintained and things to work as expected.  The ultimate answer is probably to just not use an @2x image in the first place, but to replace it with low res image since that's all the compositing is going to maintain anyway.  Alternatively you can scale the @2x image to be 640x640 (or the photo to be 1280x1280) before compositing.

Comment: Thanks for this David, posted the new code in and nothing is displayed after you take the photo though.